# Why is the recursive insertion method of the BST not working

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, insert, binary-search-tree

I wrote the following code to implement the recursive insert method for the BST. But when I print the tree in walk over order it prints the original tree before insertion. It seems as if the element was not inserted. Please help me out. Thanks in advance. Also please suggest the change in code. By the way, the intial tree in walk over order is 2 5 5 6 7 8.

```
package DataStructures;

class TreeNode {
    private TreeNode parent;
    private TreeNode childLeft;
    private TreeNode childRight;
    private int key;

    public TreeNode(){

    }

    public TreeNode(int key) {
        this(key, null);
    }

    public TreeNode(int key, TreeNode parent) {
        this(key, parent, null, null);
    }

    public TreeNode(int key, TreeNode parent, TreeNode childLeft, TreeNode childRight) {
        this.key = key;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.childLeft = childLeft;
        this.childRight = childRight;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(TreeNode parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public TreeNode getChildLeft() {
        return childLeft;
    }

    public void setChildLeft(TreeNode childLeft) {
        this.childLeft = childLeft;
    }

    public TreeNode getChildRight() {
        return childRight;
    }

    public void setChildRight(TreeNode childRight) {
        this.childRight = childRight;
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTreeBasicTest {
    private static class BinarySearchTree {
        private TreeNode root;
        private TreeNode maxNode = new TreeNode(0);

        public BinarySearchTree(TreeNode root) {
            this.root = root;
        }

        public void printTheTreeInOrderWalk(TreeNode x) {
            if (x != null) {
                printTheTreeInOrderWalk(x.getChildLeft());
                System.out.print(x.getKey() + " ");
                printTheTreeInOrderWalk(x.getChildRight());
            }
        }









        public void insertNode(TreeNode node, int key){
            if (node == null){
                node = new TreeNode(key);
            }
            else{
                if (node.getKey() > key){
                    insertNode(node.getChildLeft(), key);
                } else if (node.getKey() < key){
                    System.out.println("k");
                    insertNode(node.getChildRight(), key);
                } else{
                    // dont do anything
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(6);
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree(rootNode);
        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(5);
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode(7);
        rootNode.setChildLeft(node1);
        rootNode.setChildRight(node2);
        node1.setParent(rootNode);
        node2.setParent(rootNode);
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode node4 = new TreeNode(5);
        node1.setChildLeft(node3);
        node1.setChildRight(node4);
        node3.setParent(node1);
        node4.setParent(node1);
        TreeNode node5 = new TreeNode(8);
        node5.setParent(node2);
        node2.setChildRight(node5);
        tree.insertNode(rootNode, 3);
        tree.printTheTreeInOrderWalk(rootNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `insertNode()` method, you are just creating a new node; you are never adding the newly created node to its parent. You should check whether you are going to insert here or not or you should return the newly returned node and set it accordingly.

If you don't want too much deviation from your current program, you can make the following changes.

```
public void insertNode(TreeNode node, int key) {     
   if (node.getKey() > key) {
       if (node.left == null) { //check if you want to insert the node here
           TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(key);
           node.left = newNode;
       } else {
            insertNode(node.getChildLeft(), key);
       }
   } else if (node.getKey() < key) {
       if(node.right == null){ //check if you want to insert the node here
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(key);
            node.right = newNode;    
        } else {
             insertNode(node.getChildRight(), key);
        }
   } else {
         // don't do anything
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, parameters are passed by value. In `insertNode`, if you don't do anything else with the `node`, the line `node = new TreeNode(key);` will not do anything useful.

The typical implementation of an insertion in a tree works by returning the `TreeNode` that will replace the previous one:

```
private TreeNode insertNode(TreeNode node, int key){
    if (node == null){
        node = new TreeNode(key);
    }
    else{
        if (node.getKey() > key){
            node.setChildLeft(insertNode(node.getChildLeft(), key));
        } else if (node.getKey() < key){
            node.setChildRight(insertNode(node.getChildRight(), key));
        } else{
            // dont do anything
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Going a bit further, the previous method should actually be `private`. The `public` method should look like this:

```
public void insertNode(int key){
    root = insertNode(root, key);
}
```

Comment: In java, paramters are passed by reference and not by value...however i figured out the mistake in my code. in the first if statement a reference to a null was passed so if it is assigned to some object, it does not actually change assign the object to which the reference originally referred.

Comment: @coder12345 Your wording is quite hard to follow, but I think you are actually describing what **passing by value** is. And in Java that's how parameters are really passed: **by value**.